# How to stop a running tomcat with a java program?

Tags: java

I am writing an update program which requires the running tomcat to be stopped. I tried it with calling the net stop SERVICENAME from java but it does not work. It returns error code 2 and aborts, I guess that it's because of security reasons. Does someone know how I can solve this. Can I define that the java program runs as administrator and has therefore the necessary rights, or is there another way?

Here is my code:

```
String command = "cmd.exe /C net stop myservice";
Process p;
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor();
log.info("exit value  was "    +p.exitValue());
```

Comment: use command startup.bat

Comment: I tried it with the shutown.bat but i reive the following error: [27 Mrz 23:33:51:626]  [INFO ][The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly                                                                                       ]
[27 Mrz 23:33:56:236]  [INFO ][This environment variable is needed to run this program

Answer (score 0):

Use the SC (service control) command, it gives you a lot more options than just start & stop.
You could even start/stop services in remote machines.

USAGE:
      sc server  [command] [service name]

Comment: I tried it to call sc stop myservice but it ended with result code 5 and the server did not stop

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the <server> . I've updated the answer.